# Reading top nibble and bottom nibble in a byte

Tags: php, byte, bit-manipulation, nibble

What's the correct way to handle two distinct values being stored in one byte of data. I have a byte that contains two nibbles each containing their own data. I want to read the top nibble and the bottom nibble into their own variables.

`11110000` = High 4 bits throttle, to be read into `$throttle`, and should be a value from 0 to 15.
`00001111` = Low 4 bits brake, to be read into `$brake`, and should be a value from 0 to 15.

**Don't forget**, drivers can apply the throttle and the brake at the same time, so you might get a value like `11000111`. I've myself come up with a solution for the high 4 bits, and it's as simple as pushing the lower 4 bits out of the way with the `>>` (bit shift right) operator 4 times. `$Throttle = $ThrBrk >> 4`, but as I can't do that in one move for the lower four bits it looks kinda bad in my source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `AND`operators for both and shift the top nibble four bits to the right.

```
$brake = $value & 0x0F;
$throttle = ($value & 0xF0) >> 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [& operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), which is a bitwise AND. To get the first (least significant bit), do this:

```
$lsb = $bits & 1;
```

So, to get the whole "nibble":

```
$break = $bits & 15;
```