# Elegant & shortest way to save only half of byte

Tags: c++

Is there any elegant and shortest way how to do it?

```
unsigned char someInteger(int someInt) {
    // 00110110
    unsigned char type[7];
    type[7] = ((someInt >> 7) & 0x1);
    type[6] = ((someInt >> 6) & 0x1);
    type[5] = ((someInt >> 5) & 0x1);
    type[4] = ((someInt >> 4) & 0x1);
    type[3] = 0;
    type[2] = 0;
    type[1] = 0;
    type[0] = 0;
    return type; // 48
}
```

I'd like to have just 4th to 7th bit of the number.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading top nibble and bottom nibble in a byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909911/reading-top-nibble-and-bottom-nibble-in-a-byte). `0b00110110 & 0xF0` => 48

Comment: Even if we ignore, that this code doesn't compile, it's unclear what you are trying to do. 4th to 7th bit of what number? Do you want to extract 4 bits from a byte?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because the return type doesn't match what you're returning and `type[7]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

> Elegant & shortest way to save only half of byte

You can use bitwise AND to set half of the bits to zero. For example:

```
unsigned char byte = 0b00110110;
unsigned char mask = (1 << CHAR_BIT / 2) - 1;
unsigned char half = byte & mask;
```

> I'd like to have just 4th to 7th bit of the number.

Again, use AND with a bitmask:

```
unsigned char byte = 0b00110110;
unsigned char mask = 0b01001000;
unsigned char b_4_7 = byte & mask;
```